# How can i get audio file from google speech to text api

Tags: speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-to-text, google-text-to-speech

i am using `google speech api` to get text from **speech**. i also want to get audio file which i speak or browser recorded. Can i get this audio file. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are work in python...

```
import speech_recognition as sr

# to record audio
r = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone()

# to record audio
with mic as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
# to play audio
try: 
    text = r.recognize_google(audio) 
    print "you said: " + text 
except sr.UnknownValueError: 
    print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
```

There are a lot of parameters you can change and improve your speech recognizer. If you want to learn more check [this](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/)

Here is the code for Js...

```
var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
recognition.continuous = true;

var output = document.getElementById('output');
recognition.onresult = function(event) {
  output.textContent = event.results[0][0].transcript;
};
```

Comment: thank you for answer but i am working with js in chrome.

Comment: This is not give me sound file.